# Why are Budha and Shukra friends?

Tags: scripture, astrology, navagraha, shukra

In jyotisha, Budha and Shukra are best friends.

What is the story and reason behind it?

Comment: Budha and Sukra are Parama Mitra or only Mitra?

Comment: Also why do u think that they should not be friends? Any particular reasons?  For example we can easily understand why Budha ( reasoning/intellect ) and Brihaspati (knowledge ) are enemies.

Comment: @Rickross like there is a story of enmity between budha and chandra-"Chandra abducted Tara, Guru's consort, and thus Budha was born as illegitimate child. So budha hates chandra and sees him an enemy.". So there might also be story of friendship between Budha and Shukra. Also Shukra is beauty and Budha is speech. Without eloquence(Budha) beauty(Shukra) does not come- this may be a logical reason. But what is scriptural story behind

Comment: Without eloquence beauty does not come - How come?

Comment: @Rickross I meant that for instance

Comment: @Rickross My question here is that are there stories behind enmity and friendship between planets?

Comment: Anuragsingh Yes i understand that.